# How does reflect get the returned structure pointer

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reflection

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Blog struct {
    Name string
}

func (blog *Blog) Test() (*Blog){
    fmt.Println("this is Test method")
    blog.Name = "robin"
    return blog
}

func main() {
    var o interface{} = &Blog{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(o)
    m := v.MethodByName("Test")
    rets := m.Call([]reflect.Value{})
    fmt.Println(rets)
}
```

I got the following output:

- this is Test method
- []

Why is there no Blog struct and how to get the value of the Blog Name?

Comment: `Test` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Don't use `this` as a variable name. Name your receivers to mean something.

Comment: @tkausl  How can I get the Name value from the Blog？

Comment: @Flimzy  How can I get the Name value from the Blog？

Comment: The normal way would be: `name := blog.Name`.  Why are you using reflection?

Comment: @Flimzy This is just a demo, I want to use reflection to call the corresponding method and get the value of it based on the different struct type

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/7ug1S_mdCo

Comment: @mkopriva The page cannot be opened:Unavailable For Legal Reasons

Comment: @rowele updated the previous example with detailed names https://play.golang.org/p/iyUw-Sp97-

Comment: @rowele You can't open go playground?

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Blog struct {
    Name string
}

func (blog *Blog) Test() *Blog {
    fmt.Println("this is Test method")
    blog.Name = "robin"
    return blog
}

func main() {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(&Blog{})
    rm := rv.MethodByName("Test")

    results := rm.Call(nil)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", results)

    blogPointer := results[0]
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", blogPointer)

    blogValue := blogPointer.Elem()
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", blogValue)

    nameFieldValue := blogValue.FieldByName("Name")
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", nameFieldValue)

    name := nameFieldValue.String()
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iyUw-Sp97-

Comment: Thank you for your selfless dedication,I really can't open this website

Answer (score 1):

first we call the function returned by the interface and then we can fetch its value using Elem() method call to the pointer to interface

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

// Blog struct to hold the name of the author
type Blog struct {
    Name string
}

//Test functon to to test the blog name
func (blog *Blog) Test() *Blog {
    fmt.Println("this is Test method")
    blog.Name = "robin"
    return blog
}

func main() {
    var o interface{} = &Blog{}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(o)
    m := v.MethodByName("Test")
    res := m.Call(nil)
    ptr := res[0]
    fieldValue := ptr.Elem().FieldByName("Name").String()
    fmt.Println(fieldValue)
}
```